# Downloading remote files with PHP/cURL: a bit more robustly

Tags: php, curl

I have a script that pulls URLs from the database and downloads them (pdf or jpg) to a local file.

Code is:

```
    $cp = curl_init($remote_url);
    $fp = fopen($dest_temp, "w");
    @curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_exec($cp);  
    curl_close($cp);
    fclose($fp);
```

If the remote file is there, it works fine. If the remote file is not there, it just bombs and the browser hangs forever.

What's the best approach to handling this, should I somehow ping for the file first? or can I set options above that will handle this. I tried setting timeouts but it had no effect.

this is my first experience using cURL

Comment: What timeout values have you tried?  And have you tried both TIMEOUT and CONNECTTIMEOUT?  Also, have you checked curl_error() or curl_errno() for clues?  How about RETURNTRANSFER (does it make a difference if you write the content yourself?), or FOLLOWLOCATION (does it make a difference whether the remote request returns a location header?).

Answer (score 0):

I used to use wget much as you're using curl and got frustrated with the lack of ability to know what is going on because its essentially calling out to an external program.

I use perl WWW:Mechanize and the link below is a PHP version which might be a bit more robust for you to be able to deal with such instances.

http://www.compasswebpublisher.com/php/www-mechanize-for-php

Hope this helps.